# i cant pass the variable in alert

Tags: javascript, html

on the button click of calculate ; i want to calculate all the cost.
i'm trying btn the alert is not working on the click.

i'm trying without the variable it is working.
but when i calculate all the values and pass it in the alert function .
it just doesn't display anything.
i have also used intParse() method to typecast..

Help Needed.
Much appreciated

```js
function milkHandler() {
 var tempMilk =document.orderForm.milk.value;
 var milkTotal = tempMilk * 3.19;
 console.log(milkTotal);
}
function eggHandler() {
 var tempEgg =document.orderForm.eggs.value;
 var eggTotal = tempEgg * 3.55;
 console.log(eggTotal);
}
function breadHandler() {
 var tempBread = document.orderForm.bread.value;
 var breadTotal = tempBread * 3.49;
 console.log(breadTotal);
}
function juiceHandler() {
 var tempJuice =document.orderForm.juice.value;
 var juiceTotal = tempJuice * 4.49;
 console.log(juiceTotal);
}
function honeyHandler() {
 var tempHoney = document.orderForm.honey.value;
 var honeyTotal = tempHoney * 6.59;
 console.log(honeyTotal);
}
function finish() {
 var mainTotal = milkTotal+eggTotal+breadTotal+juiceTotal+honeyTotal;
 alert(milkTotal);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Shopping List</title>
<link href="css-pass/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<meta name="keywords" content="Reset Password Form Responsive, Login form web template, Sign up Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Login signup Responsive web template, Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyEricsson, Motorola web design" />
<!--google fonts-->
<!-- <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.main-box
{
  border: 0px solid;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.box-1
{
  border: 0px solid;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
.box-2
{
  border: 0px solid;
  height: 50px;
  width: 69%; 
  float: left;
}
.text
{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #0086E7;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>
<body>
<!--element start here-->
<div class="elelment">
    <h2>Grocery Order Form</h2>
    <div class="element-main">
        <h1>Type in the Quantities of each item you would like to purchase in the text box below</h1><br><br>
        
        <form action="" method="post" name="orderForm" onsubmit="finish()">
            <div class="main-box">  
              <div class="box-1">
                <input type="number" name="milk" onChange = "milkHandler()" id="milk"> 
              </div>
              <div class="box-2">
                <div class="text">Low Fat Milk [$3.19/Gallon]</div><br>
              </div>

              <div class="box-1">
                <input type="number" name="eggs"  onChange = "eggHandler()"> 
              </div>
              <div class="box-2">
                <div class="text">Cage Free Organic Eggs [$3.55/Dozen]</div>
              </div>

              <div class="box-1">
                <input type="number" name="bread"  onChange = "breadHandler()"> 
              </div>
              <div class="box-2">
                <div class="text">Whole White Bread [$3.49/Loaf]</div>
              </div>

              <div class="box-1">
                <input type="number" name="juice"  onChange = "juiceHandler()"> 
              </div>
              <div class="box-2">
                <div class="text">Fresh Grape Juice [$4.49/Half Gallon]</div>
              </div>

              <div class="box-1">
                <input type="number" name="honey"  onChange = "honeyHandler()"> 
              </div>
              <div class="box-2">
                <div class="text">Home Grown Honey [$6.59/Pint]</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Calcuate" >
            <input type="reset" name="calculate" value="Reset">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="copy-right">
            
</div>

<!--element end here-->
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: that was the wrong tag. sry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use variables in one function and reuse them in another. You could use `return`. But a simpler way to do this is to put everything into one function.

```js
function cal() {

var milk = document.getElementById('milk').value;
var butter = document.getElementById('butter').value;
var cheese = document.getElementById('cheese').value;

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = milk*5 + butter*4 + cheese*3;

}

function res() {

document.getElementById('milk').value = 0;
document.getElementById('butter').value = 0;
document.getElementById('cheese').value = 0;

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Value has been reset";

}
```

```html
Milk: $5 <input type="number" id="milk" onchange="cal()" oninput="cal()"><br>
Butter: $4 <input type="number" id="butter" onchange="cal()" oninput="cal()"><br>
Cheese: $3 <input type="number" id="cheese" onchange="cal()" oninput="cal()"><br>
<button onclick="res()">Reset</button><br>

Total: <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: i want to use the onchange() method in the html and create the corresponding code with that function . Could you help me with it. refer the html file

Comment: @NirmalPatel something like this?

Comment: that works. but what if i use different function for each <input> tag

Comment: @NirmalPatel . `onchange="cal();yourfunc();"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is all your variables are defined inside the functions causing them to cease existing when function ends.

You need to define these variables outside the functions.

```js
var milkTotal = 0;
var eggTotal = 0;
var breadTotal = 0;
var juiceTotal = 0;
var honeyTotal = 0;

function milkHandler() {
 var tempMilk =document.orderForm.milk.value;
 milkTotal = tempMilk * 3.19;
 console.log(milkTotal);
}
function eggHandler() {
 var tempEgg =document.orderForm.eggs.value;
 eggTotal = tempEgg * 3.55;
 console.log(eggTotal);
}
function breadHandler() {
 var tempBread = document.orderForm.bread.value;
 breadTotal = tempBread * 3.49;
 console.log(breadTotal);
}
function juiceHandler() {
 var tempJuice =document.orderForm.juice.value;
 juiceTotal = tempJuice * 4.49;
 console.log(juiceTotal);
}
function honeyHandler() {
 var tempHoney = document.orderForm.honey.value;
 honeyTotal = tempHoney * 6.59;
 console.log(honeyTotal);
}
function finish() {
 var mainTotal = milkTotal+eggTotal+breadTotal+juiceTotal+honeyTotal;
 alert(mainTotal);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Shopping List</title>
<link href="css-pass/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<meta name="keywords" content="Reset Password Form Responsive, Login form web template, Sign up Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Login signup Responsive web template, Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyEricsson, Motorola web design" />
<!--google fonts-->
<!-- <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.main-box
{
  border: 0px solid;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.box-1
{
  border: 0px solid;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
.box-2
{
  border: 0px solid;
  height: 50px;
  width: 69%; 
  float: left;
}
.text
{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #0086E7;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>
<body>
<!--element start here-->
<div class="elelment">
    <h2>Grocery Order Form</h2>
    <div class="element-main">
        <h1>Type in the Quantities of each item you would like to purchase in the text box below</h1><br><br>
        
        <form action="" method="post" name="orderForm" onsubmit="finish()">
            <div class="main-box">  
              <div class="box-1">
                <input type="number" name="milk" onChange = "milkHandler()" id="milk"> 
              </div>
              <div class="box-2">
                <div class="text">Low Fat Milk [$3.19/Gallon]</div><br>
              </div>

              <div class="box-1">
                <input type="number" name="eggs"  onChange = "eggHandler()"> 
              </div>
              <div class="box-2">
                <div class="text">Cage Free Organic Eggs [$3.55/Dozen]</div>
              </div>

              <div class="box-1">
                <input type="number" name="bread"  onChange = "breadHandler()"> 
              </div>
              <div class="box-2">
                <div class="text">Whole White Bread [$3.49/Loaf]</div>
              </div>

              <div class="box-1">
                <input type="number" name="juice"  onChange = "juiceHandler()"> 
              </div>
              <div class="box-2">
                <div class="text">Fresh Grape Juice [$4.49/Half Gallon]</div>
              </div>

              <div class="box-1">
                <input type="number" name="honey"  onChange = "honeyHandler()"> 
              </div>
              <div class="box-2">
                <div class="text">Home Grown Honey [$6.59/Pint]</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Calcuate" >
            <input type="reset" name="calculate" value="Reset">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="copy-right">
            
</div>

<!--element end here-->
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Then it will only display "0" .

Comment: Oh right sorry I overlooked another error in the code because in the Alert function there was `milkTotal` instead of `mainTotal`

Comment: so any Solutions??

Comment: i am trying the same thing it's not working . Could you mail me the files?? nimu664@gmail.com